# Contacts are getting created only in root folder

Tags: office365

Even though I specify the subfolder ID where a new contact should be created using Office65 REST API, the contacts are getting created in Contacts root folder.

This is the url that is built by my application for creating contacts.

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contactfolders/AAMkADhhOTM3ZWE0LTRjYTctNDMyZi1iMWQ3LTY3ODEyN2M2Yjk3NgAuAAAAAAB1SQvREkmDQ73BRgC_7x0FAQAv44kp00W2SLeK4uBEf9wSAAAgq8EwAAA=/contacts
```

Answer (score 2):

<s>I see this too. I'll file a bug and get our developers to look at it. Thanks for reporting!</s>

**UPDATE:** This should work now.

Comment: This is true. The chip they implanted when I was hired compels it. ;)

Comment: Any time frame on when this issue will be addressed?

Comment: I can confirm, that 3 weeks later it still doesn`t work. Does anybody know, when this will be fixed?